# How can I import a Cypher query to my Node.js logic?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I'm not a very experienced developer but I am looking too structure my project so it is easier to work on.

Lets say I have a function like this:

```
const x = async (tx, hobby) => {
  const result = await tx.run(
    "MATCH (a:Person) - [r] -> (b:$hobby) " +
    "RETURN properties(a)",
    { hobby }
  )
  return result
}
```

Can I put my cypher query scripts in seperate files, and reference it? I have seen a similar pattern for SQL scripts.

This is what I'm thinking:

```
const CYPHER_SCRIPT = require('./folder/myCypherScript.cyp')

const x = async (tx, hobby) => {
  const result = await tx.run( 
    CYPHER_SCRIPT,
    { hobby }
  )
  return result
}
```

..or will i need to stringify the contents of the .cyp file?
Thanks

Comment: you will probably need to use fs and read the file https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [@cybersam/require-cypher](https://github.com/cybersam/require-cypher/packages/336996) package (which I just created).

For example, if `folder/myCypherScript.cyp` contains this:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-->(:$hobby)
RETURN PROPERTIES(a)
```

then after the package is installed (`npm i @cybersam/require-cypher`), this code will output the contents of that file:

```
// Just require the package. You don't usually need to use the returned module directly.
// Handlers for files with extensions .cyp, .cql, and .cypher will be registered.
require('@cybersam/require-cypher');

// Now require() will return the string content of Cypher files
const CYPHER_SCRIPT = require('./folder/myCypherScript.cyp')

console.log(CYPHER_SCRIPT);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to install this package via CLI or in Package.json.